# How to use conditionals with lists

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

if I have a list for eg numbers = [78, 89, 56]
how do I use conditionals to determine whether the number 81 is larger than all the numbers in the list?

Comment: a for loop with an if

Comment: Downvoted. You have not done any basic attempt at the problem. Share your current code.

Comment: Lol, you're cruel, Dhruv... :P

Comment: @Monique As you can see, apart from me, other users have downvoted the question as well, and the reason is "lack of attempt" at your end. You can ignore my comments, but do have a look at good starting guide for stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension to generate a list of booleans representing whether 81 is larger than each element or not, and then apply [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to it:

```
>>> numbers =  [78, 89, 56]
>>> all ([81 > x for x in numbers])
False
```

Comment: I don't think, that it is necessary to perform an entire list comprehension, as that creates a new list in memory. This is especially True if it is a big list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
max(numbers) < 81
```

max(list) returns the greatest value in a list (in this case 89), then you could check whether it is smaller than 81

Answer (score 1):

you can use `max(list) < val` like MrP01 suggested.

Another way is to sort the list via sort/sorted and take the last element in the list and compare it:

```
sorted(list)[len(list) - 1] < val
```

or

```
tmpList = sorted(list)
if(tmpList[len(tmpList - 1)] < val):
   ...
```